# Como exibir informações de objetos do meu ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

Eu quero criar um `ArrayList` para armazenar informações sobre alunos (nome, numero mecanográfico e estatuto) mas não estou a conseguir fazer com que o ArrayListadicione a informação.

O codigo que eu tenho é o seguinte:

Turma.java

```
package turma;

public class Aluno {

    public String nome;
    public int nmec;
    public String estatuto;

    public Aluno(int nmec, String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.nmec = nmec;
        estatuto = "Regular";
    }


    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public int getNMec() {
        return nmec;
    }

    public String getEstatuto() {
        return estatuto;
    }

    public void getInfo() {
        System.out.print(getNome() + " - " + getNMec() + " - " + getEstatuto());
    }
}
```

TurmaMax.java

```
package turma;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 *
 * @author Z
 */
public class TurmaMax {

    public ArrayList<Aluno> turma;

    private int i;

    public TurmaMax() {
        turma = new ArrayList<Aluno>();
    }

    public void novoAluno (int nmec, String nome){
    if(turma.size() < 30) {
       turma.add(new Aluno(nmec,nome));  

    } else {
        System.out.print("Turma cheia");
    }
  }

  public void listaAlunos(){
      for (i=0; i<turma.size(); i++) {
         System.out.println(turma.getInfo()); // o erro acontece nesta linha
        }
    } 
}
```

O que tem errado no meu código?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente fazer o for desta forma:

```
for (Aluno a : turma) {
    a.getInfo();
}
```

`turma` é do tipo `ArrayList` e não possui este método. Você precisa acessar os objetos do tipo `Aluno` dentro da lista para que seja exibido corretamente.

Um detalhe, dentro do método `getInfo` você já chama o `println`, não tendo a necessidade de chamar de novo nesse método `listaAlunos()`.

---

Porém, é mais interessante tirar a responsabilidade da classe `Aluno` de imprimir coisas, deixando isso pra sua classe principal, por isso, sugiro que altere o método para o seguinte:

```
public String getInfo() {
    return getNome() + " - " + getNMec() + " - " + getEstatuto();
}
```

Com esta mudança, ai você pode usar o `println` dentro do laço:

```
for (Aluno a : turma) {
    System.out.println(a.getInfo());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Isso é porque não existe nenhum método `getInfo()` na classe `ArrayList` e `turma` é uma instância desta classe.

Talvez você queira chamar o método `getInfo` de cada `aluno`

```
public void listaAlunos(){
    for (Aluno a: turma) {
        a.getInfo();
    }
}
```

[Veja funcionando no repl.it.](https://repl.it/IW5Z/1)